# No address associated with hostname inside docker container

Tags: docker, spinnaker, flir

I am using a customized version of Ubuntu18.04 and I have a docker container where I tried to install a .deb package for the usage of a FLIR camera. To do so I downloaded from [this website](https://flir.app.boxcn.net/v/SpinnakerSDK/folder/74729115388) the file spinnaker-2.5.0.80-Ubuntu18.04-arm64-pkg.tar.gz, as suggested for Ubuntu18.04.

I followed those [instructions](https://www.flir.com/support-center/iis/machine-vision/application-note/using-spinnaker-on-arm-and-embedded-systems/) to install everything, which basically means the following commands:

```
apt-get install libusb-1.0-0
tar xvfz spinnaker-2.5.0.80-Ubuntu18.04-arm64-pkg.tar.gz
cd spinnaker-2.5.0.80-arm64
./install_spinnaker_arm.sh
```

During this process the first errors arose, which I could fix through the installation of iputils-ping and lsb-release inside the docker container:

```
apt install iputils-ping
apt install -y lsb-release
```

However, afterwards another error arose:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: 28 /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: errmsg: not found
dpkg: error processing archive libspinnaker_2.5.0.80_arm64.deb (--install):
new libspinnaker package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
ping: zone2.flir.net: No address associated with hostname

Errors were encountered while processing:
  libspinnaker_2.5.0.80_arm64.deb
```

I though it is a nework issue inside the container but I do have internet connection, which I checked through:

```
ping www.google.com
```

Does anybody has a suggestion why I am not able to install the spinnaker SDK inside my docker container? Or has an explanation for me, what "no address associated with hostname" means? I am thankfull for every hint in any direction. Maybe it is an issue because I moved my docker data folder to an external SD card?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue today.  The issue is not the ping, but instead the fact that the installer could not print the license for approval.  At line 28 of `preinst` the script tries to print an error using `errmsg` but that command does not exist, resulting in this error at the beginning of your snippet:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: 28 /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: errmsg: not found
```

Looking at the `preinst` script (I unpacked the .deb using Archive Manager), we see the true problem is that it can't display the license:[image: error in preinst]

I was able to successfully install during a `docker build` by doing the following:

1. Make sure you have **NOT** set `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` in your environment (this triggers the failure to load the license)
2. Run the dpkg/apt-get install steps explicitly in your dockerfile (don't use `install_spinnaker.sh`, as it has several places where it asks for input).  When you install `libspinnaker_*.deb`, do so like this: `(echo "yes" && cat) | dpkg -i libspinnaker_*.deb` and it will accept the license for you.  Note that you may have to re-implement all the configuration steps (udev modifications, etc) found in `install_spinnaker.sh`. (I have a GigE camera, so I don't have to worry about USB.)